# Near-Random Guessing Accuracy with Classification CNN in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I've been hesitant to ask about this here because generally I prefer to ask very specific questions rather than something along the lines of "here's a block of code, where did I go wrong?" However, I've gone through the extent of my knowledge on this and have spent quite a while troubleshooting in various ways and I could really use some external help at this point.

So I'm trying to do a relatively simple image classification with a CNN in TensorFlow as I am fairly new to machine learning. My original attempt involved 5 classes of images (32x32 with 3 color channels), and I was using around 10K but I have a data set of a few hundred thousand. I wrote out a model and whatnot, got it to train but the accuracy was always around 19-24%, which is nearly the accuracy of random guessing.

I tried isolating everything I could. I looked at the data every step of the way to make sure nothing got mismatched or lost and adjusted various parameters such as learning rate, batch size, number of epochs, etc. but nothing made the accuracy budge.

Eventually I changed up the data entirely so now I am using a data set of images of dogs and cats (still 32x32x3) that has 8k training images and 2k eval images. I also verbatim copied and pasted code that preforms well on MNIST and just changed what I needed to in order to work with the new data set (I do not intend to use stolen code, I just want to isolate everything I can while I troubleshoot). And STILL the accuracy stays at about 50%, at most reaching around 60%, which again is basically just guessing. My assumption is that there is some glaring, easy solution and so I'll include the meat of the code below in the hopes that another pair of eyes will see it (or see a more complicated issue, if there is one).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

n_classes = 2
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 32,32])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

keep_rate = 0.8
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

'''--- Generic layers ---'''
def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

def maxpool2d(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], 
padding='SAME')


'''--- Network itself ---'''
def convolutional_neural_network(x):
    weights = {'W_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32])),
           'W_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,64])),
           'W_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8*8*64,1024])),
           'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))}

    biases = {'b_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
           'b_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
           'b_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
           'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 32, 32, 1])

    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)

    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)

    fc = tf.reshape(conv2,[-1, 8*8*64])
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc'])+biases['b_fc'])
    fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate)

    output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out'])+biases['out']

    return output




def train_neural_network(x,train_data, train_labels, eval_images, 
                         eval_lables):
    prediction = convolutional_neural_network(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(
         tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction,labels=y))
         optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

            for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
                epoch_loss = 0
                for _ in range(int(len(train_data)/batch_size)):
                    epoch_x, epoch_y = train_data[_*batch_size:      
                        (_+1)*batch_size], train_labels[_*batch_size:    
                        (_+1)*batch_size]
                    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x,     
                                                                y: epoch_y})
                    epoch_loss += c


                print('Epoch', epoch+1, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)


            correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
            print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:eval_images, y:eval_lables}))
```

The structure of the network is just 2 convolutional + pooling layers and then a fully connected/dense layer. I didn't include the part of the code that actually gets the data because it's a bit cumbersome, but the images are nested python lists forming 32x32 (I flattened the color to 1 channel for simplicity). Each pixel is on the 0-255 integer scale (I originally had them normalized, made no difference). The labels are either [1,0] or [0,1].

I would appreciate any help, even if it's just to tell me where I'm being a buffoon with this issue. Also I'm sure I left out some info, so if any clarification is needed I'll add it.

On request here's the loss per epoch:

```
Epoch 1 completed out of 10 loss: 329459839.0
Epoch 2 completed out of 10 loss: 165906787.75
Epoch 3 completed out of 10 loss: 110051434.0
Epoch 4 completed out of 10 loss: 76307372.1875
Epoch 5 completed out of 10 loss: 54765472.84375
Epoch 6 completed out of 10 loss: 44318552.59375
Epoch 7 completed out of 10 loss: 34356790.765625
Epoch 8 completed out of 10 loss: 27277588.34375
Epoch 9 completed out of 10 loss: 22176274.859375
Epoch 10 completed out of 10 loss: 18461464.671875
Accuracy: 0.605
```

This is curiously higher than normal but generally the tend is similar.

Comment: shows your loses each epoch, that may help.

Comment: @vijay I can show losses for this exact code but since I've change parameters around so many times I could yield a number of different sets of losses. I'll edit the main post.

Comment: Your loses seems to be very high, try initializing the weights with a smaller value (say,stddev = 0.01).